# Powershell Renaming All Files in Folder with Counter

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I am writing a script that will rename all files in a folder to a given name (param) with in increasing counter. I want the counter to print with 3 digits (001, 002, etc). My code looks like it would work but it tells me that all my files don't exist. I also cant figure out the 3 digits correctly. Any help is appreciated!

```
param(
    [string]$NAME,
    [string]$FOLDER
    )

$NAME = "SEATTLE"
$FOLDER = "C:\Users\user00\Documents\Datasheets"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FOLDER -Recurse 
$counter = 001

foreach ($file in $files){
    Rename-Item $file.Name -NewName $NAME
    $counter++
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what padding is used for.
This is a common thing to do and well documented in many places.

Just doing a search for your use case, will return many examples.

> [powershell number padding](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20number%20padding&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20number%20paddin&sc=1-24&sk=&cvid=FCD745A0D3AB435DA468D209D0C5A76B)

[Using PowerShell to rename a portion of a file and add auto-increment, what content in my script am I missing to cause an increment to my numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745742/using-powershell-to-rename-a-portion-of-a-file-and-add-auto-increment-what-cont)

```
$i = 1
Dir xyz* | 
Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace "0101",("01{0:D2}" -f $script:i++)}
```

[Format Leading Zeros in PowerShell](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/1953/format-leading-zeros-in-powershell)

```
# Examples:
"{0:0000}" -f 4

# Results
0004

"{0:0000}" -f 45

# Results
0045

"{0:0000}" -f 456

# Results
0456

"{0:0000}" -f 4567

# Results
4567



1..10 | 
foreach {
    $i="{0:0000}" -f $_
    $dir="c:\test\Target_$i"
    $file="file_$i.txt"
    $target=Join-Path -Path $dir -ChildPath $file
    Write-Host "Updating $target"
}


# Results
<#
Updating c:\test\Target_0001\file_0001.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0002\file_0002.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0003\file_0003.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0004\file_0004.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0005\file_0005.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0006\file_0006.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0007\file_0007.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0008\file_0008.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0009\file_0009.txt
Updating c:\test\Target_0010\file_0010.txt
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$NAME = "SEATTLE"
$FOLDER = "C:\Users\user00\Documents\Datasheets"

[ref]$i = 1

GEt-ChildItem -Path $FOLDER -File -Recurse |
   Rename-Item -NewName {'{0}{1:d3}{2}' -f $NAME, $i.value++, $_.Extension}
```

The [format operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#format-operator--f) (**-f**) constructs the new mane from your base name: `{0}=$NAME`, the counter padded to 3 places: `{1:d3}=$i.Value`, and the extension of the file being renamed: `{2}=$_.Extension`

`$i` must be cast as [[ref]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6) and referenced as `$i.Value` in order to be incremented from within the scope of the script block.